# Unable select XmlNode by Xpath with two attributes

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xmlnode

I have xml as a response, need to find marked red arrow node:

[image]

My code:

```
 //response to xmlDocument
 document = new XmlDocument();
 document.LoadXml(response.Content);
 XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
 foreach (XmlAttribute curAttribute in document.DocumentElement.Attributes)
        {
          if (curAttribute.Prefix.Equals("xmlns"))
             { ns.AddNamespace(curAttribute.LocalName, curAttribute.Value); }
         }
            
 string xpath = "//edmx:Edmx/edmx:DataServices/Schema[@Namespace='Core.Entities']/EntityType[@Name='Office']/Property[@Name='OfficeKeyNumeric']";
            XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode(xpath, ns);
        }
```

I have an error that node can't be found by given XPath, node is null.

What I tried:

with `and`

```
string xpath = "//edmx:Edmx/edmx:DataServices/Schema[@Namespace='Core.Entities' and @xmlns='http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm']/EntityType[@Name='Office']/Property[@Name='OfficeKeyNumeric']";
```

without `and`

```
string xpath = "//edmx:Edmx/edmx:DataServices/Schema[@Namespace='Core.Entities'][@xmlns='http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm']/EntityType[@Name='Office']/Property[@Name='OfficeKeyNumeric']";
```

Tried also with pipe `|`, `&`  - nothing helped.

**Why it doesn't work and is it possible to make it work in that way?**

The only one working solution I'm using now is to remove `xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm"`from XML document before loading, after that my code above works fine.

```
document.LoadXml(response.Content.Replace("xmlns=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm\"", ""));
```

Comment: Did you notice that the `Schema` element also has its own `xmlns` attribute?

Comment: It would be equivalent to `<edm:Schema xmlns:edm="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">`. Think of it that way.

Comment: Yes, that is question about - how to find a node under it? I'm currently removing exactly that xmlns and related link from doc because unable to reach node if Shema has two atributes

Comment: Thank you @madreflection will try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Schema` element and its descendants are declared in the `http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm` namespace, which must be referenced in the
`xpath` statement you are looking for.

`string xpath = "//edmx:Edmx/edmx:DataServices/edm:Schema[@Namespace='Core.Entities']/edm:EntityType[@Name='Office']/edm:Property[@Name='OfficeKeyNumeric']";`

Make sure to have your `XmlNamespaceManager` initialized with these namespaces.

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("edmx","http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx");
ns.AddNamespace("edm","http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm");
```

Comment: The `edmx` alias on the root is for a namespace that has `edmx` at the end, but the `Schema` element's namespace is different; it doesn't have the `x`. It would need a different prefix.

Comment: @madreflection Missed that one while writing off from the picture. Thx!

Comment: Yeah, that looks a lot more like it. The namespaces should be known in advance, and the prefixes don't need to match the file, so explicitly building `XmlNamespaceManager` like that makes sense.

Comment: @pfx sorry for picture, that xml is huge

Comment: @Lia: You don't need to post the whole file, just as much of it as you have in the screenshot. Remember, people who are helping you might want to copy/paste it, whether it's to test something on their own or to include it in their answer. It's why we ask that all code and error messages are text (and screenshots are only supplemental).